# Telebot не отправляет эмодзи

Tags: python, telebot

При выполнении кода, который должен отправлять эмодзи выдаётся ошибка "UnicodeEncodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't encode characters in position 0-1: surrogates not allowed"

```
import telebot

bot = telebot.TeleBot('API_TOKEN')

@bot.message_handler(commands='start')
def start_message(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, '\U0000D83D\U0000DD08', parse_mode='Markdown')

bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Добавление "# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-" не помогает

Comment: что за эмодзи? не нашел таких тут https://apps.timwhitlock.info/emoji/tables/unicode

Answer (score 0):

Но можно отправлять эмодзи просто скопировав этот эмодзи с телеграмма.
Пример:

```
bot.send_message(message.chat.id, '')
```